# Export The DataBase

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I use this code to export my database but Mysql has this error:

> File 'Bill' Is Already Exists

Code:

```
    <?php
export("bill");
function export($db_name)
{
    mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    mysql_select_db("$db_name");
    $tables= array();
    $query1=mysql_query("SHOW TABLES FROM $db_name;");
        while($row1=mysql_fetch_row($query1))
        {
            $tables[]=$row1[0];
        }
        foreach($tables as $table)
        {
            $backupFile = $db_name.'.sql';
            $query = "SELECT * INTO OUTFILE '$backupFile' FROM $table";
            $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
        }   
}
?>
```

What's the problem with my code?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code.  Delete file "Bill".

Answer (score 0):

As mysql manual says `OUTFILE` shouldn't exist. So, you should check if your export file exists and `unlink` it before export your database.